# Additive norm $||a+b||=||a||+||b||$

Tags: normed-spaces

I've read somewhere that there exist spaces where $||a+b||=||a||+||b||$ is true iff $a = \lambda b, \ \ \lambda>0$.

Could you tell me what spaces have that property and what spaces don't?

$||\lambda b + b|| = |\lambda +1| \cdot||b||$ by homogeneity and I don't know what conditions should $X$ (such that $x,y \in X$) satisfy.

Could you help me?

Comment: Yes, indeed. Thank you. I've just corrected my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're looking for  [strictly convex spaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strictly_convex_space).